# clarity please on extending activity/android

Tags: android

I just want to know if I am supposed to extend every class with the following:

```
public class [name goes here] extends Activity
```

first, let me explain. below you will see an example of 4 classes I have in my project (of so many!). The Main class of course has to extend Activity. Well, within the main class are buttons. One button is for the location. I have Location extends Activity. Now, should this attend Activity, or should it extend Main? What about LocationA? Should this extend Location or Main?

public class Main extends Activity{
public class Location extends Activity{
public class LocationA extends Activity{
public class LocationB extends Activity{

Thanks for ALL of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to share a common functionality between all your activities, All your activities should extend Activity class

Comment: Okie. I just wanted to make sure. Someone told me that I should only have one extends Activity, but I thought that was incorrect because I was not receiving any errors when I did it for multiple classes. Thank you!